# Getting org.im4java.core.CommandException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: convert exception

Tags: java, imagemagick, im4java

I'm trying to use im4java in my java code to rotate a image, for this I have installed ImageMagick tool to run the code.

This is the code I have tried

```
ConvertCmd convertCmd=new ConvertCmd();
IMOperation imOperation=new IMOperation();
String imageMagickPath="C:/Users/path/to/ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI;C:/Users/path/to/exiftool-12.70";
ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath(imageMagickPath);
imOperation.addImage("LogoImg4.png");
double db=180.0;
imOperation.rotate(db);
convertCmd.run(imOperation);
```

here I mentioned the correct path for ImageMagick and exiftool. its giving below error

```
org.im4java.core.CommandException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: convert

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: convert
    at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.searchForCmd(ProcessStarter.java:661)
    at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.startProcess(ProcessStarter.java:399)
    at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.run(ProcessStarter.java:312)
    at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:215)
```

I tried the following approaches also but its giving the same error

Set the Environment variable as **IM4JAVA_TOOLPATH - C:/Users/path/to/ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI;C:/Users/path/to/exiftool-12.70**

instead of adding Global Search path I have added below also, but its giving same error

```
String imagePath="C:/Users/path/to/ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI";
convertCmd.setSearchPath(imageMagickPath);
```

I'm using **im4java version 1.4.0**

Please give me some solutions.